# What is the function of の in 「私があんた連れ出したのなんでだと思う？」

Tags: particle-の, cleft-sentences

I tried to think about all the possible meanings of の but I really couldn't understand the sentence above. I don't know if の is connected with なんで, or if it's the explanatory の, or something else.

Comment: Would you understand it if it was のは?

Comment: @AeonAkechi I considered that option but I wasn't sure of it. But if it's the case, yes, I would understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @AeonAkechiさん hinted at in his/her comment to the OP,

> 私があんた(を)**連れ出したの(は)なんでだ**と思う？

is the same as

> 私があんた(を)**なんで連れ出したんだ**と思う？

One of the things we like to do in colloquial Japanese is leave out particles like を, が and は (in their neutral forms), and even sometimes に. It can almost always be assumed from context what particles are missing, but it can be difficult if you're a new learner.

When we ask a question using a question word like 何, 誰, どこ, or いつ, we often use the pattern you found in the sentence you ask about, where we put the question word as near to the end of the clause as possible [in order to emphasize it](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72932/what-is-the-sentence-structure-in-japanese-and-how-do-you-know-the-correct-order), though this isn't only done with questions.

The の here (using the OP's specific sentence) is used to nominalize the clause 「私があんた(を)連れ出した」, after which we request further information about it using 「なんで」.

Some more examples of this phenomenon, where the second example in each pair has a stronger sense of wanting to know the requested information (what is represented by the question word).

1a) 何時に寝た？
1b) 寝たの(は)何時？

2a) 誰のクッキーを食べたの？
2b) 食べたの(は)誰のクッキー(なの)？

And one non-question where in the second case, the word at the end is being emphasized.

3a) 遅く歩くね。
3b) 歩くの(が)遅いね。

So in the case of the OP's sentence,

> 私があんた(を)連れ出したの(は)なんでだと思う？

translates to

> Why do you think I brought/took/lured(depending on context) you out?

Comment: So, what is the function of the の?  I know the answer, but you did not explain it specifically.

Comment: @sbkgs4686 wow! thank you very much!!! This is the first time I saw the は in のは being omitted!!! Also, I realized that pattern of emphasizing the information at the end before. It's common to say 〜なになに…多い, and sometimes there is even a pause in the speech to say 多い in order to emphasize it. I'd ask if it's common to omit the は particle like in the exemple sentence, but it seems to be common. Thanks for all examples. I learned many things today!

Comment: 参考までに、このパターンには[分裂文 (cleft sentence)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010)という名前があります